# Countif function only evaluating on first value in array

Tags: arrays, excel-2010, countif

My apologies if the title is not very clear (couldn't think of a better way to put my problem)...

I'm using a countif function to find all values that match two criteria, part type & code. The issue I'm having is that the criteria on part type is a range and when I try to evaluate this as an array formula, excel is only looking at the first value in the range. This is what the data looks like:

```
Sheet 1:  
PART    CODE  
1   x  
2   y  
3   z  
4   x  
3   z  
4   z  
3   y  

Sheet2:  
1   Type A  
2   Type A  
3   Type B  
4   Type B
```

I'm using a countif formula (as an array) to calculate the number of type B parts that have a code of "z". Here's the formula I used in Excel (PART & CODE are named ranges):

`COUNTIFS(PART, 'Sheet2'!$B$3:$B$4, CODE,z)`

This formula returns 2 instead of 3. When I evaluated this, Excel shows that it only finds the first value (y) and evaluates from there. I'm not sure why it is not seeing the second value (z) and evaluating that too. Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I was struggling for a bit on how to get the question formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and finally decided to try other functions (despite my initial thoughts that they wouldn't serve my purpose)...here's the final function:

`SUMPRODUCT(IF(PART=TRANSPOSE(TypeA),1,0)*IF(CODES="z",1,0)`

I had never used this function before and was thus confused when I initially read about it. After several hours of pulling my hair, I figured I had nothing to lose and forced myself to try and understand what it was accomplishing. I was so stuck on "counting" the number of occurrences that I failed to realize that by using this function with multiple IF statements, I could obtain the necessary answers (and save myself the hassle).

The TRANSPOSE function was used so that I could get the column array to be read horizontally like {1,2} instead of vertically {1;2}. I'm still not sure why my original function could not handle the vertical (unless I'm missing a fundamental aspect of arrays).